# How to put selected option in a form into a php variable?

Tags: php, html, forms

question above.

My code:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="text-center">
   <select class="form-control">
      <option value="work1">1 hours</option>
      <option value="work2">2 hours</option>
      <option value="work3">3 hours</option>
      <option value="work4">4 hours</option>
      <option value="work5">5 hours</option>
      <option value="work6">6 hours</option>
   </select>

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Go!">
</form>
```

I would like to output the selected variable in the next step.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give name to your select box. Then use `$_POST` in same file or in other file as per your requirement.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['abc'])){
    $selected=$_POST['abc'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="text-center">
<select class="form-control" name="abc">  
  <option value="work1">1 hours</option>
  <option value="work2">2 hours/option>
  <option value="work3">3 hours</option>
  <option value="work4">4 hours</option>
  <option value="work5">5 hours</option>
  <option value="work6">6 hours</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Comment: Glad it helped you:). If answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your $_POST.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['form-control'])){
        $yourvar=$_POST['form-control'];
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="text-center">
    <select class="form-control" name="form-control">  
      <option value="work1">1 hours</option>
      <option value="work2">2 hours/option>
      <option value="work3">3 hours</option>
      <option value="work4">4 hours</option>
      <option value="work5">5 hours</option>
      <option value="work6">6 hours</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Don't forget to validate the content of $_POST. You can not trust that it will always bring what you think is there.

Comment: The select menu has not been assigned a name - the above will not work